# RecycleView width and ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-constraintlayout

I Have `ViewPager`, inside `ConstraintLayout` with `RecycleView`. If I set `width` concrete in dp, the sides have empty space like this:

[image: with concrete width]

if I set `match_constraint` with references to sides:

[image]

But I want `RecycleView` fit to full `width`.

However, If I scrool down, size is correcte, but first images are incorrect!)

[image]

If I scroll up again, new added images are correct. 
[image]

How to fix this?

main.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_pager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tab_layout" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

recycle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="430dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio=""
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="335dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.529"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ViewHolder:

```
class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView imageView;


    Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener((view) -> someView.onClick(
                listItems.get(getAdapterPosition())));
    }

    void setImageView(Item item) {
        ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem(imageView);
        someView.loadImage(item, imageItem, false);
        Animation animation =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(imageView.getContext(), R.anim.scale_simple);
        imageView.startAnimation(animation);
    }


}
```

onCreateViewHolder:

```
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.picture_row, parent, false);

    return new Holder(view);
}
```

Comment: please post your main xml and list_item xml

Comment: If you scroll down and then up again, are the first rows fixed? I suspect that the problem is that the views are the wrong "size" when inflated the first time (in `onCreateViewHolder()`)... could you post your adapter code?

Comment: @BenP., code the same. I am add code to question.